# Cannot find a variable (Inheritance problems)

Tags: java, image, inheritance, variables, bufferedimage

Okay so I'm having a problem.

I have two classes: ImageHandler and PixelHandler.

In my ImageHandler class I declared:

```
public class ImageHandler{
     private static BufferedImage myImage;
     ...
```

And I try to reacess myImage in PixelHandler:

```
public class PixelHandler{
     private int [] pix;

     public int checkNumOfWindows(){
         for(int x= 0; x < 1280; x++){
              for(int y =0; y < 800; y++){
                  pix = myImage.getRGB(x, y, 6, 7, experimentalPattern, 0, 6);
              }
         }
     }
     ...
```

When I try to I get the error message:

> Cannot find symbol - variable myImage

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to extend the `ImageHandler` class?

```
public class PixelHandler extends ImageHandler {
   /* ... */
}
```

Also, derived classes cannot access private data members of their parents.  If you declared your variable as protected, then child classes will be able to access it:

```
protected static BufferedImage myImage;
```

Comment: You would also have to make myImage 'protected' instead of private.

Comment: Now in my subclass when I try to make a new constructor
public PixelHanlder(){
}

It say's that cannot find symbol - constructor ImageHandler()

Comment: I just need a blank constructor

Answer (score 0):

`private` variables are private to the class (and also not inherited) which means you cannot access them from another class. If PixelHandler is an extension of Image handler, than you should declare myImage as `protected`, not `private`. Else, you should acess this variable using `ImageHandler.myImage`, or better, declare a static method in ImageHandler to get this variable.